# Average values in the same column under certain conditions (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I am trying to find average time on and SQL server table, but only for certain entries where an ID is duplicate with an example as shown.

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |     Status       |     Date         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------| 
|          aa         |       11         |     2020-01-01   |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          aa         |       22         |     2020-02-01   |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------| 
|          bb         |         11       |     2020-01-01   |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Essentially, for all entries with a duplicate ID, find the average time it takes for that ID to go from 11 status to 22 status.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello Inchanity, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us the results that you expect, as tabular text as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use aggregation:

```
select 
    id,
    datediff(
        day, 
        min(case when status = 11 then date end),
        max(case when status = 22 then date end)
    ) diff
from mytable
where status in (11, 22)
group by id
having min(status) <> max(status)
```

This gives you one row for each `id` that has statuses `11` and `22`, with the difference in days between the date of status 11 and the date of status 22. If there are several rows with status 11 or 22, we pick the earlierst 11 and the latest 22.

Comment: ok thanks and how would i go about taking the average of the differences. bc i cant take use an aggregate function on an expression with an aggregate

Comment: You need another level of aggregation: `select avg(diff) from ( ... the above query ...) t`